# pm2 graceful restart to improve user experience and avoid problems

Tags: node.js, pm2

Is there a way to do a graceful restart of pm2 for all nodejs processes?  I'm looking for something similar to [Apache's graceful restart](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html#page-header).  Want to avoid killing a server execution in progress for every code deployment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pm2 restart` kills and restarts the process.

If you have clusters enabled, you can essentially do hot reload with 0s downtime.
`pm2 reload` should be enough for most cases.

However, what you exactly want is: `pm2 gracefulReload` which does exactly what Apache's graceful restart does. That is, it will close all existing connections before restarting.

You can find more info here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#graceful-reload